# The document appears to be corrupted and cannot be loaded

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

[image]

this is my aspose version.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
            <version>20.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

not every document will appear this exception when i call
`new Document("document file path");`

Answer (score 0):

Such exception occurs if the document is corrupted. You should report such problems in [Aspose.Words forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8) and attach the problematic document there.